# downloading zipped file from URL

Tags: python, download, zip

Well guys I come here in times of need, I've been trying to develop a batch and the first step of this batch would be downloanding a zipped file from the web, the first code that I tryied was this

```
import requests

url = "http://servicos.ibama.gov.br/ctf/publico/areasembargadas/ConsultaPublicaAreasEmbargadas.php"

save_path = "C:/Users/gb2gaet"
proxies = {
"I had to erase this for safety reasons",
}

r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies, stream=True, verify=False )
handle = open('test.zip', "wb")
for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=512):
    if chunk: 
        handle.write(chunk)
handle.close()
```

it turns out that I get a zipped file that can't be oppened, after a long search I came accross a possible solution that would be something like this

```
import requests, zipfile, io

url = "http://servicos.ibama.gov.br/ctf/publico/areasembargadas/ConsultaPublicaAreasEmbargadas.php"

save_path = "C:/Users/gb2gaet"
proxies = {
you know
}

r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies, stream=True, verify=False )
z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
z.extractall(save_path)
```

but all I ended up getting was this error message

> zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

I'd be for ever gratefull if any of you guys could help me on this matter

Comment: Is the response you received a zip file? I tried the url in chrome and just got a regular web page.

Comment: Why not just check the downloaded file? I ran your code and got html, not a zipfile.

Comment: You have posted this question with a different `url ` a few hours ago. My answer's first code downloads that file. Please check the `url` in this question. This url is not correct, it is not for a zip file. That's why the error 'zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file'

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen


open('Sample1.zip', 'wb').write(urlopen('Valid Url for Zip File').read())
```

Comment: If you test these methods against the url OP posted they will all fail because OP isn't downloading a zip file.

Comment: @tdelaney I thought he was. In fact, I downloaded his file with `open('Sample1.zip', 'wb').write(urlopen('http://servicos.ibama.gov.br/ctf/publico/areasembargadas/downloadListaAreasEmbargadas.php').read())` in another answer. It is a 6 MB excel sheet .What does he want then?

Comment: @tdelaney Can you run my code and confirm? I downloaded it with this and yes ..It is a zip file. This user posted the same question 6 7 hours ago.

Comment: Good question. The url points to a form and I guess you can fill in  the fields and get a zipfile - not sure, I don't speak the language. I think OP should fill in the form to select a zipfile to download. Its javascript and not an html form, so unless there is some way to add query variables to the url for `get`, going through a browser with selenium may be the best option.

Comment: I ran OP's code and got an html page. I'll try yours too.

Comment: @tdelaney No, I didn't have to do anything. It simply downloads the zip file.

Comment: Okay... OP seems to have changed the URL from the previous question. I used the URL OP put in this question and got the html page. Changing his code to the URL you use here, I get the same zipped xls file you see. That explains it! OP is just asking for the file in the wrong place.

Comment: @tdelaney. Yes, He has changed the `url` from the previous question. I haven't tried this one. So, I guess you are right.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Have added a comment telling the OP the same.